# Why are my layers messy and curling off the print bed?

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I use an Ender 3, with cheap Amazon "Eryone PLA", which states a range from 190-220 °C, 1.75 mm dia. I have had this for about a year.

I use the rough build plate, not the glass. I have tried my best to level the bed but I am an amateur

I was originally getting poor adhesion so I cleaned the bed, levelled it, increased filament temp to 196 °C and heated the bed to 40 °C, with no fans in a house around 20 °C with not much airflow.

This helped adhesion, but my layers are very messy - the first perimeter may adhere correctly, but subsequent layers curl off, meaning the inner passes lift off the build plate. Attempting to persevere, pulling out these regions causes the blobby, ridged mess shown below. This is still the first layer.

I have noticed the extruder makes a knocking noise every so often, and the edges of prints can be so thin they are translucent.

I've browsed the web for common 3D printing errors but nothing I've found or tried has helped.

[image: print]

Comment: If this isn't the first layer I would say over-extrusion. Are you sure the nozzle is about a sheet of paper away from the bed when Z = 0?

Comment: To the best of my ability, yes, I used a sheet of printer paper and lifted the platform until I got a small amount of resistance

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly overextrusion relative to the volume the material is being deposited into, but that doesn't necessarily mean your extrusion rate is wrong. It could be:

- Nozzle smashed down into the bed (bed way too high) but somehow still extruding
- Problem in Z axis movement preventing the head from moving up the right amount for each layer (possibly not moving up at all?)
- Extrusion (flow) increased significantly above 100% in slicer
- Wrong extruder steps/mm setting (usually controlled on printer not slicer, though you can send a setting in the start gcode)
- Misconfigued filament diameter (unlikely since there's no common setting smaller than 1.75 mm; larger setting would under-extrude)

Answer (score 2):

I'd add to [R..'s answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/13272): It could be:

- temperature is too high - which would cause the melted filament to flow a bit freely

Answer (score 1):

Bad filament is my answer. I bought PRLine and both print terrible like your picture. Suspect 2 factors, one is that the line is less than 1.75, so they underextrude and so you see those lines and in some cases gaps, second is the material itself is slippery suggesting to me that it has florinated additives.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently got my first 3D printer (Ender 3 v2) and am also using the Eryone PLA filament. After the first week, I was having bed adhesion problems as well. I think part of the problem is the bedsprings become loose rather quickly.

Here is my current solution, leveling the bed with a receipt paper (thinner than regular 20lb bond paper) and using blue painter's tape on the stock glass bed.

Since using this setup, I have not had any major issues with my prints. I have ordered new bedsprings ([Ogrimmar Yellow Springs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FY47BX7)) and hope these will be a more lasting solution to the loose bedsprings.

Comment: uh, that sounds like... bad leveling - what distance does your bed have from the carriage plate below?

Comment: @Trish currently it is about 1 cm. I was following the instructions as per this video ([Ender 3 V2 Easy Bed Leveling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JSa_r8xgX8))

Comment: 1 cm is about ok, your springs should be under lots of tension in that case.